# summarize data by group R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I am trying to get mean, sd, cv of samples that have 3 replicates. Data looks like this:

```
Sample   Titer
1        1000
1        1002
1        1006
2        2003
2        2090
2        NA
3        3020
3        3020
3        3498
```

I want output in excel format

```
Sample  mean    sd    cv
1       
2
3
```

I wrote this:

```
cv <- function(x) 100*( sd(x)/mean(x))
Re <- aggregate(titer ~ Sample, df, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), cv=cv(x)))
```

The result looks fine except that `sd` and `cv` are not considered as new columns and don't have column names
str(Re) only gives "Sample" and "titer" 2 columns.
Why? Any solution?

Then I tried to use group_by(Sample)%>%summarize(df, titer.mean=mean(titer), sd=sd(titer), cv=cv(titer))
didn't work, gave NA values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude `NA` values from all the calculations.

```
library(dplyr)
cv <- function(x) 100*( sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

df %>% 
  group_by(Sample)%>%
  summarize(titer.mean=mean(Titer, na.rm = TRUE), 
           sd=sd(Titer, na.rm = TRUE), 
           cv=cv(Titer))
```

---

You could do the same with `aggregate` but it saves all the values in a matrix in one column.

```
tmp <- aggregate(Titer ~ Sample, df, function(x) c(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                            sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), cv=cv(x)))

result <- cbind(tmp[1], tmp$Titer)
```

Comment: `aggregate` fits all the values in one column `Titler` as a matrix. I added update to the answer to show how you can use `aggregate` to generate different columns.